# addAll for Set throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, set, java-11, unsupportedoperation

Use `JDK 11.0.3`. I have the following code snippet:

```
Set<String> allNumbersSet = customerInfoService.getCustomerPhoneNumbers(bankCustomerId);
additionalInformation
        .map(info -> info.get(BANK_PE_CUSTOMER_ID_KEY))
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .ifPresent(id -> allNumbersSet.addAll(customerInfoService.getCustomerPhoneNumbers(id))); // fails here
```

Where get phone numbers is just `Collectors.toSet()`:

```
@Override
public Set<String> getCustomerPhoneNumbers(String customerId) {
    return backOfficeInfoClient.getCustByHashNo(customerId).getPropertyLOVs()
            .flatMap(property -> property.getValues().values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

However, it fails with:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.addAll(ImmutableCollections.java:76)
    at service.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.lambda$validateNewLogin$3(UserManagementServiceImpl.java:69)
```

If I update like the following:

```
var allNumbersSet = new HashSet<>(customerInfoService.getCustomerPhoneNumbers(bankCustomerId));
```

It works fine now.

***What is wrong with the above code usage? Could you explain why this exactly appears?***

---

This method call is surrounded by calling Hazelcast cache - before and after. As mentioned at comments it could be a reason for such behaviour:

> The cached values are represented using immutable collections, which makes sense, as that allows sharing without the need for defensive copies

**SOLUTION:**

Found the way how to rewrite this logic and do that stuff without merging two sets:

```
var numbersSet = customerInfoService.getCustomerPhoneNumbers(id);
if (!numbersSet.contains(newLogin)) {
    var peNumbersSet = additionalInformation
            .map(info -> info.get(BANK_PE_CUSTOMER_ID_KEY))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
            .map(customerInfoService::getCustomerPhoneNumbers)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptySet);

    if (!peNumbersSet.contains(newLogin)) {
        throw new ProcessException(ServerError.WRONG_LOGIN_PROVIDED.errorDTO());
    }
}
```

Rethink this logic a little bit:

```
var additionalInformation = Optional.ofNullable(user.getAdditionalInformation());
var phoneNumbers = new HashSet<String>();
additionalInformation
        .map(i -> i.get(BANK_CUSTOMER_ID_KEY))
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .map(customerInfoService::getCustomerPhoneNumbers)
        .ifPresent(phoneNumbers::addAll);

additionalInformation
        .map(i -> i.get(BANK_PE_CUSTOMER_ID_KEY))
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .map(customerInfoService::getCustomerPhoneNumbers)
        .ifPresent(phoneNumbers::addAll);

if (!phoneNumbers.contains(newLogin)) {
    throw new MetryusProcessException(AuthServerError.WRONG_LOGIN_PROVIDED.errorDTO());
}
```

However, understanding how exactly `Collectors.toSet()` could work under different conditions is really very useful.

Comment: @sp00m `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: On a side note, mutating a parameter isn't a great idea anyway, I would simply instantiate a new local `HashSet` as you've tried out, even if you manage to make `getCustomerPhoneNumbers` return a mutable set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc of `Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()):

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned.

So, if you need a mutable set, you should create one yourself, to be sure that it is mutable.

You can either do that with the copy constructor that you have (`new HashSet<>(...)` - don't forget the `<>`), or you could use:

`Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`

as the collector, as described in the linked Javadoc.

---

However, note that a more Stream-y way of doing this would be to concat two streams:

```
Set<String> someNumbersSet = customerInfoService.getCustomerPhoneNumbers(bankCustomerId);

Set<String> allNumbersSet =
    Stream.concat(
        someNumbersSet.stream(),
        additionalInformation
                .map(info -> info.get(BANK_PE_CUSTOMER_ID_KEY))
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
                .map(customerInfoService::getCustomerPhoneNumbers)
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: even with `collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)` UnsupportedOperationException is thrown

Comment: I checked at debug mode - it creates ImmutableCollections#Set for both cases

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried to create some demo samples. However, `Collectors.toSet()` returned a modifiable set and it works as expected. But a real project fails with `ImmutableCollections#Set`

Comment: @catch23 maybe, you have some code Instrumentation going on, like injecting a caching facility?

Comment: @Holger yes, there is Hazelcast hashing it is used exactly before and after collecting phone numbers

Comment: Then, this might be the answer. The cached values are represented using immutable collections, which makes sense, as that allows sharing without the need for defensive copies.